# Подключение сторонних библиотек Lua

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua, library, scripts

Для работы потребовалось написать пару скриптов на Lua (основной C#). Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как подключить стороннюю библиотеку к Lua. Смотрел инфу в инете по этому поводу какая есть, и то ли я не понимаю как это сделать, толи что то упускаю, но мне совершенно не очевидно как это сделать, каждый раз всегда возникает одна и таже ошибка, на все попытки подключения.

module ... not found

no field package.preload...

no file (список файлов)

Для разработки использую VS Code. Опишите пожалуйста по шагам как правильно подключить стороннюю библиотеку с нуля, желательно с примером. Мне не хватило мозгов разобраться в этом :(

Comment: выполните `print(package.path)` и увидите по каким путzv будет искаться ваш модуль, для подключения через `require()`, и к тому же можно указать полный путь к библиотеке... работает как `include` в с..

Comment: эта команда дала такой результат - путь до\source\repos\Lua test/?.lua

Comment: я делал полный путь к dll и либам, но все равно получал ошибку

Comment: ну вот значит модули ищет в `путь до\source\repos\Lua test/`

Comment: в папку с проектом я тоже кидал библиотеки

Comment: еще может быть случай , когда вы запускаете скрипт из сторонней программы, тогда относительный путь будет другим,

Comment: сделай еще `io.open("test_main_dir.txt", "w+")` - создастся файл, потом найди где он создался - вот туда можно и помещать модули, или внутри папки  использовать относительные пути

Comment: Очень странно потому что файл создался в папке с проектом, просто рядом лег. Но я пробовал кидать прямо в папку с проектом либы, но мне по прежнему выдает ошибку. Может нужно настраивать окружение и прописывать что в конфиге?

Comment: еще обратный слеш \ нужно в kua дублировать \\  в путях..

Comment: в системе переменные есть, LUA_DEV=C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1 
LUA_PATH=;;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua\?.luac 
и в path добавлены C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\clibs;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\include;
но должно работать без них, ведь у пользователя их не будет

Comment: если сторонние библиотеки подключать например require("socket.http") то нужно смотреть чтобы все файлы которые подключены внутри http.lua - тоже находились https://i.imgur.com/KQvxhuH.png

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии, помогло частично.
Теперь ошибка вылетает в скрипте socket.lua 

Возникло исключение: error loading module 'socket.core' from file 'путь до\source\repos\Lua test/socket\core.dll':
 %1 �� �������� ����������� Win32.
stack traceback:
 socket.lua:13: in main chunk
 [C]: in function 'require'
 socket/http.lua:11: in main chunk
 [C]: in function 'require'
 Codewars.lua:1: in main chunk
 [C]: in ?

Comment: попробуй эту библиотеку https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5dHy/oD9iWLpkt

Comment: Аналогичная проблема

Comment: пробуй еще к dll настроить путь в окружении VS Code, там подключить к проекту

Comment: Не могли бы скинуть пример или написать как это делать более детально? я не знаю как в VS Code это сделать, я с ним до сего момента не сталкивался.
Так же еще такой вопрос. могут ли подключенные расширения для Lua вставлять палки в колеса и мешать?

Comment: не пользуюсь VS ,  не подскажу, для начала просто сделайте свой модуль [например тут](https://ilovelua.wordpress.com/2014/01/23/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8/) ,протестируйте , потом уже решите с dll..